# Error: products.map is not a function Mern Stack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, mern

i'm working on a e-commerce mern stack and everything was working fine until i decided to deploy the app on heroku, after that this error popped up in my **HomeScreen.js** --> **map is not a function**... but before trying to deploy it, the app was working fine and i didn't encounter any problems while running both client and server concurrently to start the App.

I would really appreciate any tips or help. Thanks.

[image]

HomeScreen.js:

```
import "./HomeScreen.css";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

// Components
import Product from "../components/Product";

//Actions
import { getProducts as listProducts } from "../redux/actions/productActions";

const HomeScreen = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const getProducts = useSelector((state) => state.getProducts);
  const { products, loading, error } = getProducts;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProducts());
  }, [dispatch]);
  

  return (
    <div className="homescreen">
      <h2 className="homescreen__title">Latest Products</h2>
      <div className="homescreen__products">
        {loading ? (
          <h2>Loading...</h2>
        ) : error ? (
          <h2>{error}</h2>
        ) : ( 
          products.map((product) => (.       <-- this where the error appears 
            <Product key={product._id}
              name={product.name}
              description={product.description}
              price={product.price}
              mageUrl={product.imageUrl}
              productId={product._id}
            />
          ))
        )}
      </div>
      
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

Product.js:

```
import "./Product.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Product = ({ imageUrl, description, price, name, productId }) => {
  return (
    <div className="product">
      <img src={imageUrl} alt={name} />

      <div className="product__info">
        <p className="info__name">{name}</p>

        <p className="info__description">{description.substring(0, 100)}...</p>

        <p className="info__price">${price}</p>

        <Link to={`/product/${productId}`} className="info__button">
          View
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

ProductActions.js:

```
import * as actionTypes from "../constants/productConstants";
import axios from "axios";

export const getProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: actionTypes.GET_PRODUCTS_REQUEST });

    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/products");

    dispatch({
      type: actionTypes.GET_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: actionTypes.GET_PRODUCTS_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};

export const getProductDetails = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: actionTypes.GET_PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST });

    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`);

    dispatch({
      type: actionTypes.GET_PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: actionTypes.GET_PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};

export const removeProductDetails = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: actionTypes.GET_PRODUCT_DETAILS_RESET });
};
```

server.js:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const path = require('path');
const express = require("express");
const productRoutes = require("./routes/productRoutes");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");


connectDB();

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

//--------------- deployment -------

__dirname = path.resolve();
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/frontend/build')));

  app.get('*',(req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend','build','index.html'))
  })
  
} else {
  app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Api running");
  })
}


app.use("/api/products", productRoutes);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

.env:

```
PORT=5000

MONGO_URI=**********************

NODE_ENV=development
```

.env.local:

```
NODE_ENV=production  

PORT=5000

MONGO_URI=************
```

Answer (score 0):

> products.map((product) => (.       <-- this where the error appears

Setting this to `Array.isArray(products) && products.map((product)` should fix this as it will only run when the products is an array, otherwise the block won't execute.

However, it will only prevent the error from not showing up. You'll still have to debug and check at which point the value isn't being set.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help, i did as you told me and it gotta rid of the error, but i want to display the items and i can't seem to figure out the problem.... but this was working before deployment, why isn't working now ?

Comment: are you getting the proper response? if not that could be one reason.. if yes then I guess the value isn't being updated after the response is received. try adding logs and debug each step to get into depth

Comment: Okay i found the error, in **.env** i had to change **NODE_ENV** to production instead of development... so if i want to deploy it to heroku  i have to change it to production, but i will get this error again !  do you have any idea why this's happening ??

Comment: set production in local env file and test  the flow where its failing & fix the error.. then it should work on prod too

Comment: I created **.env.local** and added the **production** instead of development, i just wanted to ask a question regarding the testing... do i create a `jest.config.js` for testing or how does it work... am not quite familiar with testing environments, i also updated the code so you can check...thanks.

Comment: I meant testing the features on the browser.. not the tests.

Comment: I changed it to **Production**, but i got the same the error again... **TypeError: products.map is not a function** in my HomeScreen.js... i tried to add the products? like this `) : products? (` and then the `products.map()`.. but i gotta syntax error...what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

just add question mark after products like this => `products?.map(...)`

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, i did as you asked, but it showed a **Syntax Error**, i even tried to add the products?  like this  `) : products? (` and then the `products.map()`, but i also gotta a **Syntax Error** as well... am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: which version of react did you use?

Comment: I'm using version 17.0.2, does that make a difference ?